# directly posting/ paste large URLS into tinymce editor not working as responsive

Tags: php, responsive-design, tinymce

I have a TinyMCE editor for a blog website. When a user directly pastes large URLs into the TinyMCE editor is not looking responsive while displaying on the blog. The blog site is responsive with box layouts. While displaying these big URLs are coming out of the box and the layout is disturbing. 
For example `https://google.com` is looking good, but when the user pastes large URLs then they are coming out of the box. Is there any option in TinyMCE to break that large string based on the layout? Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This issue seems not to be with TinyMCE but with your layout when you render the URL.

Have you looked at using `overflow-wrap: break-word;` in your CSS?

http://fiddle.tinymce.com/Krgaab